# Swift Print Anchor Constant Value

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How do you print out the value of an anchor's constant? For example:

```
let myButton = UIButton()
myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
myButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
print(myButton.topAnchor.constant)//this would print 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constant is for the constraint that you have laid out for the anchor. Anchors *don't* have constants. **Constraints** do. So what you need to do is maintain a reference of the **constraint** and access the constant.

```
let myButtonTopAnchorConstraint = myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 5)
myButtonTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = true
myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
myButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

print(myButtonTopAnchorConstraint.constant) //Prints 5
```

A view will have only **one** `topAnchor`, but can have multiple constraints relative to that anchor.